# How can I get correlation plot between survey responses (R)?

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, data-visualization, survey

I am performing an analysis on a survey response with answers like(most likely, not at all,a lot). I want to see correlation between responses of two columns. For eg, does "a lot" of one column correlate to " a lot" of the other column? I want to 1. find correlations and 2. visualize the same. What would be the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be to convert those responses into numbers according to their ordering (e.g. "not at all" becomes 1, "most likely" becomes 2, and "a lot" becomes 3), and then compute the correlation between two columns using Spearman correlation. If your columns are called `x` and `y`, for example, then you could compute this using `cor(x,y,method='spearman')`.

If you are interested in correlations between many pairs of columns, you can produce visualizations of all these different correlations using, e.g., the package [corrplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html). You can create a matrix containing all the correlations of your column pairs using `M <- cor(mat,method='spearman')` (if your data, in numerical form, are all contained in `mat`) and then input `M` into the functions described in the linked vignette.